# Dropdown for min and max values, not updating in EI9 and IE8 JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have these drop downs with numerical values to select a min and a max value, when you select a value on either of the dropdowns the other should update to remove the values not in range, for example:
If min = 15,000 -> max options will start on 15,000 and will not show the 10K and 5K options

HTML

```
<div class="filters" id="size-filters">
<select id="sf-size-min" name="sf-size-min" class="price-dropdown">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="none">Space Min</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="5000">5,000</option>
    <option value="10000">10,000</option>
    <option value="15000">15,000</option>
    <option value="20000">20,000</option>
    <option value="25000">25,000</option>
</select>
<select id="sf-size-max" name="sf-size-max" class="price-dropdown">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="none">Space Max</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="5000">5,000</option>
    <option value="10000">10,000</option>
    <option value="15000">15,000</option>
    <option value="20000">20,000</option>
    <option value="25000">25,000</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(function(){

var all_values=[];

var initial_options=$('#sf-size-min').get(0).options;
for(i=0; i<initial_options.length; i++)
{
    var val=parseInt(initial_options[i].value);
    var lbl=initial_options[i].label;       
    all_values[i]={value: val, label: lbl };

}

document.getElementById('sf-size-min').options;//$('#sf-size-min').get(0).options;

$('#sf-size-min').change(function(){
    var $src=$('#sf-size-min');
    var $target=$('#sf-size-max');
    var prev_max_value=$target.val();
    var current_min_value=$src.val();

    //clear max drop down list
    $target.get(0).options.length=0;

    var j=0;
    for(i=$src.get(0).selectedIndex; i<all_values.length; i++)
    {
        $target.get(0).options[j++]=new Option(all_values[i].label, all_values[i].value);
    }
    $target.val(prev_max_value);


});

$('#sf-size-max').change(function(){
    var $src=$('#sf-size-max');
    var $target=$('#sf-size-min');
    var prev_min_value=$target.val();
    var current_max_value=parseInt($src.val());

    //clear min drop down list
    $target.get(0).options.length=0;

    var j=0;
    for(i=0; i<all_values.length;  i++)
    {
        if (current_max_value > all_values[i].value)
            $target.get(0).options[j++]=new Option(all_values[i].label, all_values[i].value);
    }
    $target.val(prev_min_value);
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/dianaavila/2UEr6/2/

This is working great on FF, Chrome and IE10. But on IE9 and 8 I get an empty list after the update.

Thank you for your help.

***Update: The issue is that the target object doesn't have a label, trying to find out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer it was super simple and obvious! And somehow my fault.

the "option" tag didn't have a "label" attribute. Most of the browsers were able to figure out that the text between the opening and closing tags can be taken as a label but not IE8 and 9.

So I just added the "label" attribute and its content and ta-da!

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2UEr6/4/

Updated HTML

```
<div class="filters" id="size-filters">
<select id="sf-size-min" name="sf-size-min" class="price-dropdown">
    <option label="Space Min" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="none">Space Min</option>
    <option label="0" value="0">0</option>
    <option label="5000" value="5000">5,000</option>
    <option label="10000" value="10000">10,000</option>
    <option label="15000" value="15000">15,000</option>
    <option label="20000" value="20000">20,000</option>
    <option label="25000" value="25000">25,000</option>
</select>
<select id="sf-size-max" name="sf-size-max" class="price-dropdown">
    <option label="Space Max" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="none">Space Max</option>
    <option label="0" value="0">0</option>
    <option label="5000" value="5000">5,000</option>
    <option label="10000" value="10000">10,000</option>
    <option label="15000" value="15000">15,000</option>
    <option label="20000" value="20000">20,000</option>
    <option label="25000" value="25000">25,000</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I've been looking for solutions for hours and this one fixed it. We had angular populating options with `ng-repeat`, which wasn't working in IE8. Adding `label="{{item}}"` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple thing, but not adding

```
<DOCTYPE html>
```

Can have this effect as it tells the browser to read it as the latest version of html.  Beside that there is no reason your code should not work.  (I tried you code on ie8 with a doctype specified and it worked fine) Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply, I do have doctype specified on the complete website  :)

Comment: I thought you would have, but even the most experienced web designers forget simple things so worth a check!